# Do the following sentences mean exactly the same?

Tags: paraphrasing

I tried to paraphrase the first one and wrote the second sentence. Is it correct? I mean, are they the same in the meaning?

> 1. Napping can reduce sleep debt and improve cognitive functioning.
> 2. Napping can offset the impact on cognitive functioning of sleep debt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences do not mean the same thing.

In the first sentence "sleep debt" and "cognitive functioning" are *separate things* that are mentioned.

In the second sentence only one thing is mentioned, "cognitive functioning." This is described as being impacted by sleep debt.

(In addition, "impact on cognitive functioning of sleep debt" is not idiomatic. Instead: "impact of sleep debt on cognitive functioning.")